# Access to value of a Table Item

Tags: string, vaadin

I am doing a Vaadin project and maybe it's easy question but my brain is stop working right now.

I have a Table which code is like:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.addContainerProperty("Value", String.class, "");
table.addContainerProperty("combo", ComboBox.class, null);

table.addItem(new Object[]{"asd123", combo1}, 1);
table.addItem(new Object[]{"asd1234", combo2}, 2);
```

combo1 and combo2 are ComboBoxes, their code is like:

```
ComboBox combo1 = new ComboBox();
combo1.addItem("Choice 1");
combo1.addItem("Choice 2");

ComboBox combo2 = new ComboBox();
combo2.addItem("Girls");
combo2.addItem("Boys");
```

I want to access an item on table, and hold this as String.
Assume that there is a String str and String str2 variables, and I want that (str = asd123) and (str2 = combo2's selected element).

How can I do that?

If you can help, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

```
table.getItem(itemId);
// or
combo2.getValue();
```

However, these functions both return Object values so you have to typecast them to String before using them properly.

```
String str = (String) table.getItem(itemId);
```

For further reference see [Vaadin Table](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html) and [Vaadin ComboBox](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html).

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried to use them but like your saying they both return Object. When I typecasting, I take a NullPointerException.

Comment: That's not because of typecasting. You must be forgetting setting some values to those properties when you launch your application.

Assuming you don't set values in your code (adding items and setting values are not the same) when your app launches, the fields will be null initially.

You should add a button or something similar to retrieve your newly set values in the application.

If you're sure you're setting them correctly, then you must focus on retrieving those values with a button or even server push.

Comment: When I am adding item, can't I set value too? I mean "asd123" is not the value? In following code I am using a button like your saying. And I want that, this button take asd123 value to a String variable and also get user's choice via ComboBox and store this another String variable. How can I do that? The project's next steps, I will store them in a constructor and store this constructors in a List. Because of that I need that String values.

Comment: The selected item is the value in the table and the combobox when you launch the app. At first nothing is selected so these values are null. User has to select an item first. Yes "asd123" is a value but it has to be selected by the user when the program is running. After selection, the user clicks a button and inside this button's listener these values can be get() and assigned to a String.